# Scale ImageMap coords with dynamic sized images

Tags: jquery, image, scale, imagemap, imagemapster

I'm looking for a way to make my dynamically scaled images fit with the image maps i'm making.
I'm using jquery to scale the images with the window size:

```
$(window).bind("load resize", function(){

        $(".post img").height($(window).height()-110);
        $(".post img").width(($(".post img").newHeight() / $(".post img").oldHeight()) * $(".post img").oldWidth());

});
```

But ImageMaps I make stay true to the original size. I'm looking in to ImageMapster, but cant figure out how to automatically make all the imagemaps scale.

This is the page it's for:
http://www.dersuawesome.com/home/

Answer (score 3):

In **imagemapster** you use: $('img').mapster('resize',width,height,duration);

citation from the original imagemapster documentation:

> $('img').mapster('resize',width,height,duration);
>       ---
>       image: new width of the image  OR
>       height: new height of the image
>       duration: (optional) 0 | milliseconds (to animate the resizing)
>        This will resize the image map to the dimensions specified. Note that either width > or height should be passed, and the other will be
>   calculated in the same aspect ratio as the original image. If you pass
>   both, only the width will be used to calculate the new dimensions: the
>   proportions must remain the same as the original image.

end of citation.
eg. when an image should become 900 pixel wide you use:

```
$('img').mapster('resize',900,null,2000);
```

Here I told imagemapster to use 2000 milliseconds for this resizeing to get a smooth effect.
Putting this into the onconfigured-section of the code works well for me:

```
onConfigured: function(){
         $('img').mapster('resize',900,null,2000);
        } ,
```

Comment: addendum: the author of imagemapster has a complete resize-example here: http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html#resize

Comment: addendum2: another complete example from the author of imagemapster is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jamietre/jQG48/

Comment: But doesn't this resize it to a predetermined size. I need the imagemaps to automatically fit the image size

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding you. But when I understand your problem correct than the example, which I did mention in my addendum2, should solve your problem. did you take a look at this example?